# Slug поле - помогите разобраться?

Tags: python, django

Имею класс телефоны, где есть поля - `id`, `name`, `price`, `image`, `release_date` и `slug`.

Задание такое:

> Значение поля slug должно устанавливаться слагифицированным значением поля name.

Не могу понять что от меня хотят и как это можно реализовать?

Comment: От вас хотят, чтобы из имени «Вася Пупкин» получался slug «vasya-pupkin»

Comment: Вам нужна эта функция https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) `Slug` - это газетный термин, это короткая метка для чего-то, содержащая только буквы, цифры, нижние подчеркивания и дефисы. Они в основном используются для `URL`ов.

Я предполагаю, что этот класс находится в файле `models.py` вашего приложения. Если это так, то для того чтоб выполнить задание необходимо просто добавить поле, которое будет `SlugField`. Что нибудь такое

```py
from django.db import models

class Phone(models.Model):
    id = ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 254, null=False)
    .....
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 200)
```

Если не указывать входной параметр `db_column` для поля `SlugField`, то автоматически будет использовать значение из поля `name`, что вам и требуется.